# How can I use `setState` with objects nested in an array in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

With this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/0ggDnlOoL), I am able to successfully use `setState` on a simple object – when I click on "Joey" the name changes to "Igor".

```
    class Card extends React.Component {
        myFunc = () => {this.props.change('Igor')};
        render() {
            return (
                <p onClick={this.myFunc}>{this.props.name}</p>
            )
        }
    }

    class Parent extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = { name: "Joey" }
        }

        toggle = (newname) => {
            this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
                name: newname
            }));
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <Card change={this.toggle} name={this.state.name} />
            );
        }
    }
```

But with this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/wmxjQBRv8), which has multiple objects nested in an array, `setState` is either not able to change each name to "Igor" or it must be modified in some way.

```
    class Card extends React.Component {

        myFunc = () => {this.props.change('Igor')};
        render() {
            return (
                <p onClick={this.myFunc}>{this.props.name}</p>
            )
        }
    }

    class Parent extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                names: [
                    {
                        name: "Joey"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Sally"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Billy"
                    },
                ]
            }
        }

        toggle = (newname) => {
            this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
            // what can I put here to change the name I click on to "Igor"
            }));
        }

        render() {
            const names = this.state.names.map((name, index) => (
                <Card key={index} change={this.toggle} {...name} />
            ))

            return (
                <div>
                    {names}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Even though I know this is not how `setState` works, I tried to access `name` by passing `index` and then writing `this.state.names[index].name: newname`. No surprises here, it didn't work.

I have researched and cannot find similar questions on SO about this although I have found a lot of mentions with regards to immutability helpers. But I am still not sure if that is the way to go.

What is the best way to use `setState` to modify objects nested in an array?

Comment: `this.setState(this.state)`?

Comment: How will you know which one is clicked? You need some identifier, such as the index of the specific `Card`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have modified your code and the working example can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/n5oj7KxA5).

The changes can be found here:

```
toggle = (index, newname) => {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        // Return new array, do not mutate previous state.
        names: [
            ...prevState.names.slice(0, index),
            { name: newname },
            ...prevState.names.slice(index + 1),
        ],
    }));
}

render() {
    const names = this.state.names.map((name, index) => (
        // Need to bind the index so callback knows which item needs to be changed.
        <Card key={index} change={this.toggle.bind(this, index)} {...name} />
    ))

    return (
        <div>
            {names}
        </div>
    );
}
```

The idea is that you need to pass the index into the callback function via `.bind`, and return a new `state` array with the modified name. You need to pass the index so that the component knows which object to change the `name` to `newname`.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you Tay. This works but for others who may see this later – **I failed to mention in my original question** that I wished to avoid using `.bind(this)` for the reason given [here](https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/) (see "Way #2). With Tay's help, I was able to rewrite my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/rk5mMP5L4) without using `.bind(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this for the toggle method:

```
toggle = (nameYouWantChanged, nameYouWantItChangedTo) => {

  this.setState({
    names: this.state.names.map(obj => 
      obj.name === nameYouWantChanged
        ? { name: nameYouWantItChangedTo }
        : obj
    )
  })

}
```

Comment: Thank you Brad, this is pretty clever. You have a missing `)` on line 7 that should come after `: obj` but this is a great solution. I have modified my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/YzRwAgy0) so that others can see how this solves the problem.

Comment: Brad, also just wanted you to know that I chose Tay's solution over yours because his use of `index` keeps problems from arising, for example, in situations where multiple objects in the array may share the same name.